# How to write PHYSFS_file and Save

Tags: c++, file, physfs

I am working with PHYSFS lib and am having some problems.

problems:

**1** - is there any way that after I use the method

```
PHYSFS_file* filew = PHYSFS_openWrite(fileName.c_str());
```

I change the filew to READ?

**2** - How do I do to save the file, for example I used the method 
PHYSFS_write need and saves it in a different file, how I do it.

**3** - I would like to add a word at the beginning of the file, I'm trying this:

```
std::string str = "TESTS";
char *data = str.c_str();

PHYSFS_file* filew = PHYSFS_openWrite(fileName.c_str());
PHYSFS_write(filew, data, strlen(data), 1);
PHYSFS_close(filew);
```

But I'm not having good results.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why is the question tagged C? It looks like you're using C++. What does "not having good results" mean? Be more specific. And what have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry must have been some mistake in time to enter, I tried this in the question, the number 1 and 2 I do not know how I would do and what I've tried 3 in this question. 
thank you

Comment: I don't think there's a way to change access mode of an already open file, other than closing it and re-opening with different flags.Regarding 2 - not sure what you mean by "saving". Writing to a file, then closing it IS "saving" already. If, however, you want to copy/rename/move it to another file afterwards, then you're out of luck: PhysFS just does not have these features as far as I know. I stumbled upon this myself some time ago, and ended up implementing copying with OS-specific APIs.

Comment: Regarding 3. If I understand correctly that you are trying to "insert" a string into the beginning of an existing file, without overwriting any existing data (i.e. prepend), then again, I don't think there is any special feature for this. A straightforward solution would be to read the entire file into a separate buffer, then overwrite the file by writing first your string, and then the original data from your buffer. Of course, if you need to do it with BIG files, you'll have to get a bit more creative - e.g. read and overwrite it block-by-block...

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying many doubts on this issue Buffers would you give me a simple example? 

Thank you again